# Animate a subview by flipping to another subview in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, subview

I have a view with 2 subviews in it that are hidden below the screen. What I currently have setup is when a user clicks a button in the main view it animates both subviews on top. When this happens only 1 of the subviews is being shown while the other is behind it.

What I am trying to do is when both subviews come up and when the user clicks on a button in the subview it should flip to the other view. However, when I tried to accomplish this nothing happens. Below is the snippet of code I am using inside the button's `TouchUpInside` of the first subview:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.StatisticsScreen cache:true];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a similar approach also. What I did was programmatically to create an `UIView` (called `panelView`) in which I added both of my views I needed to flip and then when a button is pressed:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.panelView 
                      duration:0.5f 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                    animations:^{

                        [self.view1 removeFromSuperview];
                        [self.panelView addSubview:self.view2];

                    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Where and when did you create the panelView and add the subviews to the newly created view? And can you update your answer with the example? I'm just trying to figure out why I have to create a new view just to animate between two already existing views.

Comment: You can make it in the nib and add the 2 views inside or you can make it programmatically: UIView *panelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]; then [panelView addSubview:view1] and the same for view2. I did this, because all my views were inside a scroll view and the flipping animation was not working correctly - it was flipping the other views in scroll view. Give it a try this way i am sure it will work.

Comment: This just made the view disappear. do I need to add the panelView onto the mainView?

Comment: Yes, otherwise nothing will be visible

Comment: This kind of worked. There was no animation and the second view is being displayed offset. Where the first view was centered in the parent view; the second view is showing up in the bottom right corner. Why is animating a flip so difficult as compared to a scroll.

Comment: did you have a loop of uiviews or just one uiview ? Because when I do the same my last view in a loop of uiview gets disappeared for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Add both Subviews to the Superview, make one subview set to hidden, And the following code

```
    if(!isSelected){
         isSelected = YES;

         [UIView transitionWithView:superview
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{

                        [subview1 setHidden:YES];
                        [subview2 setHidden:NO];

                    } completion:nil];
}else{
    isSelected = NO;
    [UIView transitionWithView:superview
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{

                        [subview1 setHidden:NO];
                        [subview2 setHidden:YES];

                    } completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.StatisticsScreen cache:true];

[view addSubview:theViewYouWantToAppear];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Of course, the subview has beed already added, so the only effect of calling `addSubview` is changing the subview order.

Comment: That's the old animation API—you should use the block-based API instead.

Comment: @kevboh: I am using what the OP is using... possibly this could be required in order to support iOS 3...